# BIM in AngularJS or Laravel, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5, bim

I have a question about whether it is possible to create a functionality in AngularJS or Laravel that would allow opening BIM files?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Hi, you can try to use XeoGL (http://xeogl.org)

Answer (score 0):

A very quick guide to importing IFC models into xeogl: https://github.com/xeolabs/xeogl/wiki/Importing-IFC-Models